# Why do I not see the thrown exceptions in a Cucumber "Around"?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have a set of cucumber tests that get run on a build server.

I often want faster feedback than the server directly provides and so I watch the console output as it runs. I was wanting a way of identifying any failing test with a single search term so I modified our Around to print "Failed Test" on any exception, but Ruby doesn't seem to be handing the exception back up to the around. I've verified this by having puts statements after the begin ... end.

Does anyone know why this is happening or a way of wrapping any exception thrown from a failing test in a begin?

```
Around() do |scenario, block|
  begin
    Timeout.timeout(0.1) do
      block.call
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error => e
    puts "Failed Test"
    puts caller
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "Failed Test"
    raise e
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't exist, as i'm trying to do the same :/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at cucumber 1.3.12 it actually rescues any exceptions from scenario steps. So you can't see them in any way without modifying cucumber gem.

See my answer on how to put a debug hook in that place for more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22654786/520567

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried disabling Cucumber's exception capturing with the @allow-rescue tag?

@allow-rescue: Turns off Cucumber’s exception capturing for the tagged scenario(s). Used when the code being tested is expected to raise and handle exceptions.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags

Comment: I just want to add cause no one commented on this, but @allow-rescue only works with cucumber and rails configs